# Как из таблицы, в которой записаны изменения получить выборку на каждую дату?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица с изменением цен на товары (поля: product_id, date (дата изменений), price (новая цена)).
Нужно сделать выборку, в которой на каждую дату будет product_id и его цена в эту дату. Как это сделать?

Подумал, что можно сделать cross join дат и product_id, но не знаю, как заполнить NULL в столбце price

Comment: @Mike `... DESC`

Comment: @Akina кстати вообще не работает  ... :) думаю что бы с ним сделать

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224332/window-function-ignore-nulls-workaround-for-postgresql